# Custom order summary in email

Tags: magento2, orders, email

**Is there any possiblity to build custom order summary form in emails?**

I'd like to build custom table which I can style as needed since editing files in **Magento_Sales/templates/email/*** doesn't have much effect.

Or how could I at least edit Totals? They seem to be generated right from the system.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find order email template here :
app/design/frontend/VendorName/themeName/Magento_Sales/email/order_new.html
app/design/frontend/VendorName/themeName/Magento_Sales/email/order_new_guest.html

You have a `order` object that contains all what you need.
You can find the class here `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php`
and find all the methods you need ex . `getBaseTotalPaid()`

In you template just put the code :

```
{{trans "Your total: %total." total=$order.getBaseTotalPaid()}}
```

In `app/design/frontend/VendorName/themeName/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml` the total is call : `<?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>`